# Database not updating after calling TableAdapter.Update() Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, ms-access-2003, strongly-typed-dataset

I have an existing Access 2003 Database that I imported into a Outlook 2003 AddIn Project. VS 2005 then generated the `DataSet` based on the one table I had in my database. Below is the code I use to add a row to the table:

```
        public CustomPropertiesDataSet.CustomPropertiesRow addItem(string id, string projectnumber, string task, string overtime, string category, string subcategory, string finished)
        {
            CustomPropertiesDataSet.CustomPropertiesRow newrow = this.NewCustomPropertiesRow();

            newrow.ItemID = id;
            newrow.Projectnumber = projectnumber;
            newrow.TaskDescription = task;
            newrow.Overtime = overtime;
            newrow.Category = category;
            newrow.Subcategory = subcategory;
            newrow.Finished = finished;
            try
            {
                this.Rows.Add(newrow);
                newrow.AcceptChanges();
                this.AcceptChanges();
                custompropertiesadapter.Update(this);                
            }
            catch(System.Exception ex)
            { }


            return newrow;            
        }
```

My problem here is that the tabe doesn't get updated. When I debug, I see that the `DataSet` contains the new row, but not the database.

Comment: nobody can say anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

I will go out on a limb and suggest that you need to move 'this.Rows.Add(newrow);' to a point BEFORE you are setting all the field values.  I believe the '.Add' initializes the row, which would wipe out your previous settings (or in a prior lifetime, 'Add, populate, save'.

Comment: In fact you *are* out on a limb here because the 'New row, fill it up, add it' pattern is pretty standard - in fact it's necessary to do it in this order in situations where there are constraints on the dataset. As to the OP's problem, my own out-on-a-limb suggestion is that the db he's looking at is not the one he's adding to - iirc there are scenarios where the db is copied to another folder at runtime; but I don't even know what an Outlook 2003 AddIn project is so I'm keeping my mouth shut ;-)